# Prove $(k+1)\binom{n}{k+1}+k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n}{k}$ for integers $0\le k\le n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, binomial-theorem

> Prove $(k+1)\binom{n}{k+1}+k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n}{k}$ for integers $0\le k\le n$

I need help, I've been trying to factor all day and can't figure it out.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. You can also prove $(k+1)\binom{n}{k+1}=(n-k)\binom{n}{k}$ [another way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)). Hint: in how many ways can you choose a committee of $k+1$ people with a chairperson?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): edit your post to show your attempts.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3072810

Answer (score 0):

Before I start my answer, I believe I should state that you should type that instead of using an image.

Proof:

$(k+1)*\binom{n}{k+1} +k * \binom{n}{k}= \frac{k+1}{(k+1)!*(n-k-1)!}+\frac{k*n!}{k!*(n-k)!}$

$= \frac{n!}{k!*(n-k-1)!}+\frac{k*n!}{k!*(n-k)!}=\frac{(n-k)n!}{k!*(n-k)!}+\frac{k*n!}{k!*(n-k)!}$

$=\frac{n(n)!}{k!(n-k)!}$

$=n*\binom{n}{k}$

as required.

Answer (score 0):

$${n \choose k+1} = \frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!} =\frac{n!}{\frac{k+1}{n-k}k!(n-k)!} = \frac{n-k}{k+1}{n \choose k}$$